# Create or replace view hive

Tags: view, hive, hiveddl

What is the similar syntax for create or replace view(which exists in RDBMS) in hive.
For example,
Create or replace view as select * from table1.

I know there is syntax **create if not exists.**

But in my case, view exists in lower environment, so i want to replace and view if doesn't in higher environment , i need to create.

Since i need to do source-code once and deploy in all environments. I need similar code to create or replace view.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW
```

feature was introduced in Hive 0.8 in Jira [HIVE-1078](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-1078)

Also there is ALTER VIEW as SELECT as of Hive 0.11 (View must exist)

```
ALTER VIEW [db_name.]view_name AS select_statement;
```

On Hive version < 0.8 and if upgrade is not possible use DROP+CREATE

```
DROP VIEW [IF EXISTS] [db_name.]view_name;
CREATE VIEW [db_name.]view_name ...
```

Comment: There is a create or replace for view in hive, I've literally just used it

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW database.tableview AS SELECT (...) FROM database.mastertable

Comment: @Dee Interesting... Which Hive version are you running?

Comment: @Dee Thanks, found that Jira, it is HIVE-1078, and the version 0.8. So strange that the documentation is not updated yet